# StringBuilder not appending int to beginning of string unless 0 or 10

Tags: c#, string, list, unity-game-engine, stringbuilder

I have a bowling game that takes the list of bowls and then runs them through this code to produce a string that goes through the frames on the UI. If the user bowls a gutter (0) or strike (10) the code works fine. However, if it is between 1 and 9, it fails to produce a string. Why is this? I've searched and tried many other ways to do this, but this seems to be the only way it will work.

```
public static StringBuilder FormatRolls (List<int> rolls) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i=0; i < rolls.Count; i++) {
        if (rolls.Count >= 19 && rolls[i] == 10) {                                          //Bonus End-Frame Strike
            output.Append ("X");
        } else if (rolls[i] == 0) {                                                         //Gutter
            output.Append ("-");
        } else if (rolls[i-1] + rolls[i] == 10 && rolls.Count > 1) {                                            //Spare
            output.Append ("/");
        } else if (rolls[i] == 10 && rolls[i+1] == 0) {                                     //Strike
            output.Append ("X");
        } else {                                                                            //Normal bowls 1-9
            output.Append (rolls[i].ToString());
        }
    }

    output.ToString();

    return output;
}
```

This is the code that then writes to all of the frames:

```
public void FillRolls (List<int> rolls) {
    StringBuilder scoresString = FormatRolls(rolls);
    for (int i=0; i<scoresString.Length; i++) {
        frameText[i].text = scoresString[i].ToString();
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've been stuck for DAYS trying to get this to work...

Comment: Are you sure you have other values in rolls?

Comment: Values are added to rolls before it calls the script, so there will always be something in rolls.
And no, not a break, but I do have a try-catch method to move past populating the strings in case `FillRolls()` fails
`try {
   scoreDisplay.FillRolls(rolls);
   scoreDisplay.FillFrames (ScoreMaster.ScoreCumulative(rolls));
  } catch {
   Debug.LogWarning("FillRollCard failed");
  }`

Comment: For code like this, it's often easiest to sprinkle some `Console.WriteLine` statements into the if-else cascade and see which branches are executed. Outputting the value of `rolls[i]` in each loop iteration helps as well.

Comment: In Unity 3D you may want to use `Debug.Log` or (`LogWarning`, `LogError`) instead of `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rolling through all the comments and suggestions from others, I took away the try-catch section that blocked me from seeing past my catch error. Then, added debug.log statements to help find the correct position and used Unity's built-in errors to find this wasn't the string's fault at all. It was trying to find an index `rolls[i]-1` that didn't exist. After a few attempts I found that if I changed the `else if (rolls[i-1] + rolls[i] == 10 && rolls.Count > 1)` to a nested if statement and used the `output.Length` instead of `rolls.Count` it would no longer return an error. Thank you everyone who tried to help me solve this, you pointed me in the right direction and really got me thinking! Here is the finished code:

`public static string FormatRolls (List<int> rolls) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();`

```
    for (int i=0; i < rolls.Count; i++) {
        if (rolls.Count >= 19 && rolls[i] == 10) {                                          //Bonus End-Frame Strike
            output.Append ("X");
        } else if (rolls[i] == 0) {                                                         //Gutter
            output.Append ("-");
        } else if (rolls[i] == 10 && output.Length % 2 == 0) {                              //Strike
            output.Append (" X");
        } else if (output.Length >= 1 && output.Length % 2 != 0) {                                                  //Spare
            if (rolls[i-1] + rolls[i] == 10) {
                output.Append ("/");
            }
        } else {                                                                            //Normal bowls 1-9
            output.Append (rolls[i]);
        }
    }

    return output.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`output.ToString();` is a pure function and you are not using its return value (so, you are converting to a string, and then throwing that string away without using/storing/returning it). I guess you really want to return the fully built and formatted string, not the StringBuilder instance. Use:

```
return output.ToString();
```

That said, other codepaths should not produce a value either.

Comment: Also, you don't need `output.Append(rolls[i].ToString())`, `output.Append(rolls[i])` should suffice, due to the multiple overloads of StringBuilder.Append()

Comment: Thanks, that has let me take the `public static StringBuilder FormatRolls` and change it back to the original `public static string FormatRolls`. I have also changed the `Append()` after looking into the reference for it. I'm pretty new to this, thank you for your help! However, I am still not getting the output, unless a 0 is first in line for StringBuilder. Not even 10 is coming through anymore...

Comment: @Magic: have you added debug statements to see which values you get and where it breaks?

Comment: Ok so, getting rid of the try-catch code enabled me to get into the debugging part and have my lines go thru regardless if it works or not... Now to the important:  line `else if (rolls[i-1] + rolls[i] == 10 && rolls.Count > 1)` is where it breaks because `rolls[i-1]` doesn't exist, it throws and ArgumentOutOfRangeException, but why would it do that when I also check that `rolls.Count > 1`?

Comment: If only I would've commented out the try-catch WAY earlier... this question is very different now... It makes sense that when only 0 would be passed thru everything else would work because then `rolls[i-1]` is actually there and it checks 0 first thing before the code could break. Otherwise it would throw the exception and break. I feel silly... @CharithJ was right in his comment above and I flew past it.